# Is it possible to get all revisions of multiple entities in hibernate enver?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers, audit-logging

I have an orders table and is being audited with hibernate envers @Audited.
I need to show user the list of orders along with the history of each order(add, modify, process).

How can I achieve this with hibernate envers audit?
How to fetch all revisions for multiple entities in one go?

I know how to get the revisions of one entity(using forRevisionsOfEntity()).

Expected Sample response like

| Order ID | Status | Rev |
| --- | --- | --- |
| O1 | Completed | 3 |
| O1 | Processed | 2 |
| O1 | Created | 1 |
| O2 | In progress | 2 |
| O2 | Created | 1 |